# My program prints 0 instead of the expected number

Tags: c

So I made a function that returns a value which is the connection (sum) of 2 numbers that the user gives. But everytime I enter these 2 numbers, the result is somehow always 0.

```
float connection(int num1, int num2, float result)
{
    result= num1 + num2;
    return (result);
}

int main()
{
  int num1= 0;
  int num2= 0;
  float result= 0.0;

  printf("\nChoose the first number you'd like to connect: ");
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  getchar();
  printf("choose the second number you'd like to connect: ");
  scanf("%d", &num2);
  connection(num1, num2, result);
  printf("The result is: %f", result);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is (I believe) that you expect the argument `result` you pass to the function to change value. That's not how C works, instead all arguments are passed *by value* and the variable `result` inside the called function is a local variable which has no connection to the `result` variable in the calling function. Changing one variable will not affect the other.

Instead use the value the function returns:

```
result = connection(num1, num2, result);
```

Of course, this means passing `result` as an argument is totally meaningless, and you don't even need it in the function:

```
int connection(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Also note that I changed the return-type, as adding two integers will never result in a floating-point number.

---

On a side-note to modify the argument means you have to pass it *by reference*, which is not supported by C. It can be *emulated* though, by using pointers:

```
void connection(int num1, int num2, int *result)
{
    *result = num1 + num2;
}
```

Then call it as

```
int result;
connection(num1, num2, &result);
```

Comment: I think it is a bit unsafe to assume _"you expect the argument result you pass to the function to change value."_, because the function was assigned a return value and so on. I think it is more _probable_ that the person just forgot to assign. But hey, that's just an opinion, and who knows! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up two possibilities: returning a value and changing a variable by passing it to a method as a reference.

This is how to return a value (in this case, you don't need the `result` parameter):

```
float connection(int num1, int num2)
{
    float result= num1 + num2;
    return result;
}

...

result = connection(num1, num2);
```

This is how to pass a variable as a reference (in this case you don't need a return value):

```
void connection(int num1, int num2, float *result)
{
    *result= num1 + num2;
}

...

connection(num1, num2, &result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think forgot to assign your result back to your variable:

```
connection(num1, num2, result); // returned value is missed

result = connection(num1, num2, result); // returned value saved
```

If, instead, you want your function to modify the variable, C is passed by value so you need some pointers:

```
void connection(int num1, int num2, float *result)
{
    *result = num1 + num2;
}

connection(num1, num2, &result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your function call **pass by reference**

```
#include<stdio.h>

float connection(int *num1, int *num2, float *result)
{
    *result= *num1 + *num2;
    return (*result);
}

int main()
{
  int num1= 0;
  int num2= 0;
  float result= 0.0;

  printf("\nChoose the first number you'd like to connect: ");
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  getchar();
  printf("choose the second number you'd like to connect: ");
  scanf("%d", &num2);
  connection(&num1, &num2, &result); //Function Called by reference 
  printf("The result is: %f", result);
}
```

For further details on function calls [Read It](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)